# Call a specific constructor to map @requestBody

Tags: java, spring, constructor, request-mapping, dynamic-mapping

I have a post call method and the method parameter is annotated with @ReuqestBody for class say A. Now, inside of my class A, there is a variable of type B and that class has couple of subclasses.
In the request, I am passing enum for sub-type of B and want to intialize my requestBody based on the sub-type.

```
class A {
    B b;
    ...

    A(Subtype S, B data) {
         // I need to initialize A based on subtype (my B's class would be dynamic here)
    }
}

class B {
    String s1;
}

class C extends B {
    int x;
}

class D extends B {
    double d;
    String s2;
}


class XYZController {

    public Resp doThis (@RequestBody A, @PathVariable SubType) {

    }
}

enum SubType {
    C ("C")
    D ("D")
}
```

So the overall structure is something like this.
Now, based on what I'm passing as subtype, I want to create that kind of object.
I'm kind of confused on how Spring calls the constructors while doing such mappings. Any lead would really help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: so you are saying "I want to create that kind of object" so use '?' in requeset body and use simple if-else in your service layer.

Comment: Yeah, that's another way to go about it. I am not quite sure how the constructors gets called in case of requestbody mapping. So, I was trying to check if I can do this during injection itself instead of doing it later in service layer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not exposing every APIs available? I make sense to have specifics APIs and not a generic one.

it's the KISS pattern : Keep It Simple Stupid. It could allow you to enhance the affordance of your APIs.

Something like this :

```
@PostMapping(value="/mypath/v1/something-usefull-for-api-a")
public Resp doThis (@RequestBody A) {

}
@PostMapping(value="/mypath/v1/something-usefull-for-api-b")
public Resp doThisForB (@RequestBody B) {

}
@PostMapping(value="/mypath/v1/something-usefull-for-api-c")
public Resp doThisForC (@RequestBody C) {

}
...and so on...
```

Comment: doThis() function is a @postmapping. So are you suggesting to create multiple post mappings for same endpoint? 
This will not scale well if the parameter type increases from A.B.C. to A.B.C.D....N

Comment: I have edited my response to be as clear as possible. From my point of view, you should drive your API specification with : One definition/exposition -> One implementation. Your code will be more maintainable
 if you use contract first vs code first

Comment: Yeah, this was the plan in case the runtime DI didn't work. But my concern remains the same, the type A has possibility of having more than just 2 or 3 subtypes and this way would not be as maintainable.